# Only updates the last row in database

Tags: php, mysql

Im building a backend for admin, for school project, to change the product data. This is the code I have for the forms

```
         dbCon();
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE categoryid = 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database.');
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == NULL) {
mysqli_close($dbc);header("Location:index.php?l=f");exit();
}
echo "<h1>Middlefartvej:</h1>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$name = $row['name'];
$price = $row['price'];
$image = $row['image'];
$productid = $row['productid'];
echo "<li>";
echo "<img src='".$image."' alt='Food_pic' style='height:100px'>";
echo "Change picture: <input name='image' type='text' class='' value='".$image."' onFocus='this.value=' placeholder='".$image."'/>";
echo "<input name='productid' type='text' class='' value='".$productid."' onFocus='this.value=' placeholder='".$productid."'/>";
echo "Change name of food:<input name='name' type='text' class='' value='".$name."' onFocus='this.value=' placeholder='".$name."'/>";
echo "Change price: "." "."<input name='price' type='text' class='' value='".$price."' onFocus='this.value=' placeholder='".$price."'/>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" class="loginButton">';
echo "</li>";
}
```

But now I can only change the last form field, if I change something else it doesnt do anything. Here is the editing code

```
dbCon();

//get the variables



$name = $_POST["name"];
$categoryid = $_POST["categoryid"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$image = $_POST["image"];
$productid = $_POST["productid"];


//update the database with newdata that user has inserted

$query= "UPDATE product SET  name='".$name."', price='".$price."' , image='".$image."' WHERE productid = '".$productid."';";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: What `<form>` are you using? There isn't one in your code. You probably need to wrap each separate `<li>` in a separate form; otherwise, only the last row is submitted because each row overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: <form method="post" action="editing.php"> This is what im using, im not sure if this is what you asked

Comment: Kinda, yes; where is it in your PHP? If you have everything in one form, then you'll have multiple elements with the same name - each row has an `image`, `productid`, etc. So when you submit the form, all that data is submitted, and only the information from the final row is added, because all the earlier ones have been overwritten.

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer, and accept it when you can ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about some debugging?  Echo out the value of the $query variable before you execute your query.  Is that statement valid?  Does it execute from a sql command line or phpmyadmin?

Off the top of my head, this looks suspect:

```
$query= "UPDATE product SET  name='".$name."', price='".$price."' , image='".$image."' WHERE productid = '".$productid."';";
```

If productid is an integer you don't need or want to put single quotes around it, as it is not a string.  Also you don't include an end semicolon to a statement using the client library.  PHP Interpolation can take care of a lot of this for you rather than you trying to concatenate all the time to get around escaping double quotes.

```
$query= "UPDATE product SET name='$name', price='$price', image='$image' WHERE productid = $productid";
```

With that said, you should be using bind variables for all your input, rather than interpolating into the query.

See:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php